# How do I only generate protobuf messages for the import path?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

If I have the following directory structure:

```
├── proto
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── date.proto         # No dependencies
│   │   ├── user.proto         # No dependencies
│   ├── services
│   │   └── service1.proto     # import "common/date.proto"; (doesn't import common/user.proto)
```

When I run the following:

```
protoc -I=proto/\
  --go_out=paths=source_relative:./gen \
  proto/services/service1.proto
```

Only code for `service1.proto` gets generated, `date.proto` does not.

So instead I use the glob pattern:

```
protoc -I=proto/\
  --go_out=paths=source_relative:./gen \
  proto/**/*.proto
```

But this also generates `user.proto`, which is bloating the codebase as our schema has hundreds of files.

Is there anyway to just generate proto files on the import path without specifying the dependencies via the `protoc` command?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such magic, as `protoc` does not look into your proto source files to resolve the dependency tree. You have to tell `protoc` where to search for imported protos. Also imports are just dependencies, `protoc` does not generate code for dependencies, unless for those are also sources.

You may want to do:

```
protoc -I=proto/\
  --go_out=paths=source_relative:./gen \
  proto/services/service1.proto proto/common/date.proto
```